# How to allow post request in django rest framework correctly?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

How to allow post request in django rest framework correctly?

Now I get an error while create POST request to api/v3/exchange/order (use POST)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/skif/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/skif/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/skif/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/skif/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/skif/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/skif/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 495, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/skif/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/skif/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/skif/PycharmProjects/beex2/app_ccxt/external_api.py", line 44, in post
    return getattr(self, self.name)(request)
  File "/home/skif/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/skif/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/skif/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 478, in dispatch
    request = self.initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/skif/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 382, in initialize_request
    parser_context=parser_context
  File "/home/skif/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 160, in __init__
    .format(request.__class__.__module__, request.__class__.__name__)
AssertionError: The `request` argument must be an instance of `django.http.HttpRequest`, not `app_ccxt.external_api.ApiExternalCCXT`.
[08/Jul/2019 15:40:31] "POST /api/v3/exchange/order HTTP/1.1" 500 44749
```

I try to change request instance to  HttpRequest and nothing changed.

my code in external_api.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets
from beeqb.models import *
from rest_framework import status
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializer import *
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from beeqb.handlers.WalletHandler import select_wallet, get_crypt_wallet, make_sub_wallet
from django.db.models import Q, Sum
import requests
import json
from beeqb.handlers import ChartHandler, OrderHandler, WithdrawHandler, AddressHandler
from rest_framework import generics
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
import pytz
import time
from .api_lib import *
from beeqb.handlers.ChartHandler import *
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, schema
from rest_framework.schemas import AutoSchema
from beeqb.models import Order, OrdersTrigger, ORDER_WAIT, ORDER_BUY, ORDER_SELL, ORDER_DONE
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
import logging

class ApiExternalCCXT(APIView):
    name = ''
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return getattr(self, self.name)(request)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return getattr(self, self.name)(request)

    @api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
    def api_create_order(self, request):
    “““
    the method must accept POST requests
    HERE SOME CODE
    “““

    def api_get_fetch_orders(self, request):
    “““
    the method accepted GET requests and working fine
    HERE SOME CODE
    “““
```

my urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from django.conf.urls import include, url
import beeqb
from .views import ApiCCXT, ApiOrder, Ticker, SymbolsDetails, ApiTransactions, ExampleView
from .serializer import *
from rest_framework.documentation import include_docs_urls
from app_ccxt.external_api import ApiExternalCCXT
import app_ccxt.ChartHandler
from app_ccxt.ApiCCXT.ChartHandlerCCXT import ApiChartHandlerCCXT
urlpatterns = [
  “““ URLS “““
    url(r'^exchange/order',        ApiExternalCCXT.as_view(name='api_create_order')),
  “““ URLS “““

    url(r'^exchange/fetch_open_orders',  ApiExternalCCXT.as_view(name='api_get_fetch_open_orders')),

  “““ URLS “““

]
```

If I try to excute GET rquest for  api_get_fetch_orders method (exchange/fetch_open_orders) – all working fine.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get post request in  api_create_order method? What is wrong in def post() ?

I think all problems in post() but can not understand how i can modified it for using in several methods. I need POST request for this method and several others

I am using for GET request: return getattr(self, self.name)(request)

Similarly, I wanted to do with the POST reqursts. But here i have error.

If Im using only GET requests for method api_create_order (I removed post() and @api_view notation from code) all working fine too.

Can you help me with it?

**UPD:**
POST/GET requests for api_create_order() method with post() and  @api_view notation.

For POST request:
Request information:

```
USER: AnonymousUser

GET: No GET data

POST:
aaa = '123'
bbb = '234'

FILES: No FILES data

COOKIES: No cookie data
```

for GET request

```
Request information
USER     AnonymousUser
GET
Variable    Value
token    '521f5013121d0829a946780cb5763ea41042c132'

number  '1139012'

POST 
No POST data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how code should be organized. More of `REST` Approach.

```
class OrderApi(ListCreateAPIView):
    name = ''
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """This is to fetch the list."""
        return Response()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """This api to create the order."""
        return Response()

    # No need of `api_create_order` and `api_get_fetch_orders` function.
```

And your urls

```
urlpatterns = [
  “““ URLS “““
    url(r'^exchange/order', OrderApi.as_view())]
```

Comment: if i do that my other methods wil not work. I'll think about create new class for it.

Comment: Yes, this will make your code less coupled and high cohesive.